# Source that the world was created for amalek

Tags: sources-mekorot, creation, amalek

Numerous Midrashim list different things that the world was created for the purpose of such as Klal Yisrael, Bikkurim, Torah, Challah, and Maasros all of which are called "ראשית" (first).

I remember seeing somewhere (along with a very nice Vort for it) that one of the things the world was created for was Amalek because Amalek is called Reishis in Bamidbar 24:20

> במדבר כד:כ - וירא את עמלק וישא משלו ויאמר ראשית גוים עמלק ואחריתו עדי אבד:

Does anyone know what the source for this is? Thanks.